# How to change entity name in SwiftData

Tags: migration, swift-data

I'm working with SwiftData in coredata project.

I have coredata models (Event, EventDate, Lecture), and convert to swiftdata model using Model macro.

```swift
enum V3Schema: VersionedSchema {
    static var models: [any PersistentModel.Type] = [Event.self, Lecture.self]
    
    static var versionIdentifier = Schema.Version(3, 5, 2)

    @Model public class Event {
        var date: Date?
        var memo: String?
        var status: Bool? = false
        var title: String?
        var lecture: Lecture?

        public init() { }
        
    }

    @Model public class Lecture {
        var color: String?
        var room: String?
        var title: String?
        @Relationship(deleteRule: .cascade, inverse: \Event.lecture) var events: [Event]?
        @Relationship(deleteRule: .cascade, inverse: \LectureTime.lecture) var times: [LectureTime]?
        

        public init() { }
        
    }
}
```

I want to change entity name in other version like code below.

```swift
enum V4Schema: VersionedSchema {
    static var models: [any PersistentModel.Type] = [LectureModel.self, EventModel.self]
    
    static var versionIdentifier = Schema.Version(4, 0, 0)

    @Model class EventModel {
        var title: String = ""
        var status: EventStatus = EventStatus.incomplete
        var memo: String?
        var deadline: Deadline?
        var lecture: LectureModel?
        
        struct Deadline: Codable, Comparable {
            static func < (lhs: V4Schema.EventModel.Deadline, rhs: V4Schema.EventModel.Deadline) -> Bool {
                lhs.startAt < rhs.startAt
            }
            
            var startAt: Date
            var endAt: Date
            var isTimeRequired: Bool
        }
        
        enum EventStatus: Int, Codable {
            case incomplete = 0
            case complete = 1
        }
        
        init(eventID: String, title: String, memo: String? = nil, date: Deadline? = nil, status: EventStatus = .incomplete) {
            self.eventID = eventID
            self.title = title
            self.memo = memo
            self.deadline = date
            self.date = deadline?.startAt
            self.status = status
        }
        
    }
}
```

I wrote migration plan for change model, but migration plan wasn't called. (I add log for checking migration is working, but logs not appeared.)

```swift
enum ModelMigrationPlan: SchemaMigrationPlan {
    static var schemas: [any VersionedSchema.Type] = [V3Schema.self, V4Schema.self]
    static var stages: [MigrationStage] = [migrateV3ToV4]
    
    static let migrateV3ToV4 = MigrationStage.custom(fromVersion: V3Schema.self,
                                                     toVersion: V4Schema.self,
                                                     willMigrate: { _ in 
    Log.debug(message: "Migration Start")
    \\ create new EventModel in V4Schema using Event in V3Schema.
},
                                                     didMigrate: { _ in Log.debug(message: "Migration Complete") })
    
}
```

question1. How to change entity name in SwiftData?
question2. How can use heavyweight migration in SwiftData?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look here: https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftdata/how-to-create-a-complex-migration-using-versionedschema.

There isn't (yet?) a simple way to migrate a database if you want to change the Entity name, which will mean under the hood to change the database table name.

But it is, of course, possible if you follow the approach described at the linked article.

Comment: Your answer would be better if it provided more details about the solution. If the link goes bad, this answer will have lost all value.